# Is NT SERVICE a local or shared network domain account?

Tags: windows, sql-server

The sql agent job runs under the NT SERVICE/InstanceName account.

Is the NT SERVICE domain private to the current computer or is it shared across all computers in the network?

Answer (score 1):

NETWORK SERVICE and LocalSystem will authenticate themselves always as the correpsonding account locally (builtin\network service and builtin\system) but both will authenticate as the machine account remotely.

See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806582

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Managed Service Accounts, Group Managed Service Accounts, and Virtual Accounts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-ver15#New_Accounts) doc, you'll see it's a virtual account:

> - **Virtual Accounts**
>   Virtual accounts (beginning with Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows    7) are managed local accounts that provide the following
>   features to    simplify service administration. The virtual account is
>   auto-managed,    and the virtual account can access the network in a
>   domain    environment. If the default value is used for the service
>   accounts    during SQL Server setup, a virtual account using the
>   instance name as    the service name is used, in the format NT
>   SERVICE<SERVICENAME>.    Services that run as virtual accounts access
>   network resources by    using the credentials of the computer account
>   in the format    <domain_name><computer_name>$. When specifying a
>   virtual account to    start SQL Server, leave the password blank.